# Patent US5007257 still in force (confused because of assignments after expiration)?

Tags: us5007257

In reference to the patent: [US5007257](https://www.google.com/patents/US5007257)

When did or when does this patent expires? Since it was filed on 9. Okt. 1990 I think it expired 20 Years later on 9. Okt. 2010.

But what confuses me is that there where legal events (assignments) after the assumed date of expiration (Why to make assignments if the patent is already expired?!). See here  http://www.google.com/patents/US5007257#legal-events

I am not experienced with patents and hope somebody can help me with the question if this patent is still in force or not.

Thank you very much,
Simon

Comment: Note that the PTO does not review any information filed in the patent assignment database for accuracy or legality. Thus, you can file whatever assignments you want--even legally void assignments--with the PTO and they will dutifully post that information. If you want to be sure, have a lawyer obtain the actual legal document affecting the assignment from the USPTO (give them the reel/frame number, which corresponds to the microfilm system used by the PTO).

Answer (score -1):

The lifetime of a patent is 20 years.
This patent has already expired. 
I found that the proprietor has changed,  maybe due to a change of name. 
I can imagine that this is done out of economical reasons to link the former patent with the firm. So of you are interested in the matter you will contact the right firm. Just a guess though.